# Private and public queues on MSMQ

Tags: msmq

Is it possible for server A to access a private queue from server B?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is little functional difference between a public and private queue, except that MSMQ publishes information about public queues in Active Directory (AD).

I've never done this myself, but it appears that if you know the full path to the private queue, you can access it from another server:

> **Private queues**
>
> Private queues are queues that are not
>   published in Active Directory and are
>   displayed only on the local computer
>   that contains them. Private queues
>   have the following features:
>
> Message Queuing registers private
>   queues locally by storing a
>   description of the queue in the LQS
>   (local queue storage) directory on the
>   local computer. In MSMQ 2.0, and
>   Message Queuing 3.0, the default
>   location is
>   %windir%\system32\msmq\storage\lqs.
>   Note that a description of each public
>   queue created on the local computer is
>   also stored locally in a separate file
>   in the LQS folder.
>
> Private queues are registered on the
>   local computer, not in the directory
>   service, and typically cannot be
>   located by other Message Queuing
>   applications.
>
> **Private queues are accessible only
>   by Message Queuing applications that
>   know  the full path name, the direct
>   format name, or the private format
>   name of  the queue, as follows:**
>
> Path
>   name:ComputerName\private$\QueueName.
>
> Path name on local computer:
>   \private$\QueueName.
>
> Direct format name::
>   DIRECT=ComputerAddress\PRIVATE$\PrivateQueueName.
>
> Private format name:
>   PRIVATE=ComputerGUID\QueueNumber.
>
> For more information on path names and
>   format names, see Queue names.
>
> Private queues have the advantage of
>   no directory service overhead, making
>   them quicker to create, no latency in
>   accessing them, and no replication
>   overhead.
>
> Private queues are not dependent on
>   the directory service, and thus can be
>   created and deleted when the directory
>   service is not working. This is useful
>   for offline operation.
>
> One way that private queues can be
>   exposed to other applications is by
>   setting a message property. To
>   distribute the location of a private
>   queue, an application can send a
>   format name of the private queue as
>   the response queue property of a
>   message.

[Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776346(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: It seems like you will most likely hit a number of brick walls. Use this link to try and fix them (three bulletpoints containing links to new pages for specific solutions) : [MSMQ from the plumber's mate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx)

Comment: plumber's mate link now broken :(